# Is it possible to download an MP3 file instead of playing inside the browser in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to download an MP3 file just by clicking on it in Google Chrome? Currently, it starts playing the file in the embedded player.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + click on the link.

Comment: It's not a link, it's an embedded player.

Comment: The embedded player of Chrome (plug-in?) starts once you click on a link pointing a mp3 file, try it.

Comment: It downloads a .mpeg here, not the .mp3 itself...

Comment: It downloads the file pointed by the link (whatever it is, even an HTML page), if the link points to 'file.mp3' Chrome will download it. I can't see your problem, here everything works as expected.

From the Google Chrome guide (http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=25799&from=25799&rd=1):

Press Alt and click a link.  Downloads the target of the link.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the capacity to test this right now, but if I remember correctly, when the embedded music player comes up, can't you just go to the file menu and hit "Save Page as..."?

Alternatively, Holding CTRL and hitting S should do the trick as well.

Edit: I went out of my way to test, and it does work.

Comment: So simple, yet brilliant lol

Answer (score 1):

[Orbit Downloader](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/) can do this for you.

Comment: Use oGet along with Orbit and chrome seems perfect :)
`https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/lfjamigppmepikjlacjdpgjaiojdjhoj`

Answer (score 1):

If you have URL to mp3 song, then paste it in address bar of chrome. It will start playing the song. Then right click -> Save As... OR Crl+S to save the mp3 being played.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: This answer provided better clarity.